# Linux installation cd environment

Tags: livecd, installer

I recently made a custom Linux system, for my special need.

It's on my HDD, but I want to create a cd for installation.

A few days ago, I found a live cd and created an install script for that, but because of power failure my HDD is gone, and I cant find that live cd again.

My install script is based on recovering tar.gz backup.

My requirement is as follows:
   based on glibc (not uclibc)
   recognize every devices

Do you have any suggestions?